# Can a $9 \times 9$ grid be filled in with $81$ numbers - i.e., ${1,2,3,\ldots,81}$ such that the sum of any $3\times 3$ grid within it is the same?

Tags: combinatorics

Can a $9\times 9$ grid be filled in with $81$ numbers (i.e., ${1,2,3,\ldots,81}$ such that the sum of any $3\times 3$ grid within it is the same?

I was thinking of doing some coloring like that of strominos but could not really proceed with that.
On the other hand, I saw the interesting intersecting bars (i.e., how if we take $2$ squares with common elements we can state some facts about some of the bars). Although this just gave me a bunch of equalities but not something I could make use of.
I am trying to find a contradiction since it feels quite unbelievable with such conditions. A nice insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Notice that if you have a three by three grid and you make another just by shifting a row ove that means the some of any three cells must be the sum of the corresponding three cells three cells over.  That will severely limit your hand I would think.

Comment: @CalvinLin I think the OP means *any* 3x3 grid.  Not just the 9 separate ones.  There are 49 such sets of 9 elements.  Not just $9$.

Comment: (K, my original hint applies) Write each of the 81 numbers as $ 9i+j$, with $ 1 \leq j \leq 9$. Arrange them such that A/ in any $3\times 3$ grid. the various $i$ are from 1 to 9, and the various $j$ are from 1 to 9, and B/ the $(i, j)$ values are distinct, which makes $9i+j$ distinct. Then, the sum in any grid will be $9(1+2+...+9) + (1+2+...9)$ hence constant.

Answer (score 0):

I used [MiniZinc](https://www.minizinc.org) to solve this question experimentally as constraint programming problem:

```
include "globals.mzn";

% problem dimensions
int: n = 9;
int: subN = 3;
set of int: N = 1..n;

%  decision variables
array[N, N] of var 1..n*n: x;
var int: sum3_3;

%  cells have to be all different
constraint all_different(x);

%  all 3x3 sub-grids have to have the same sum
constraint 
  forall(top in subN..n, 
         right in subN..n, 
         bottom in 1..top-subN+1, 
         left in 1..right-subN+1, 
         vmid in bottom+1..top-1, 
         hmid in left+1..right-1)
  (
    sum3_3 = sum([x[row, col] | 
                  row in {top, vmid, bottom}, 
                  col in {left, hmid, right}])
  );
```

The answer was "unsatisfiable".

For the simple case with $3\times3$ non-overlapping contiguous subgrids, I've found the following solution with subgrid sum 369:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
8 &  1 & 17 & 13 &  2 & 49 & 41 &  3 & 35 \\
\hline
11 & 79 & 72 & 56 & 78 & 40 & 64 & 36 & 44 \\
\hline
81 & 57 & 43 & 50 & 66 & 15 & 67 & 65 & 14 \\
\hline
52 &  4 & 60 & 34 & 27 & 19 & 31 & 61 & 22 \\
\hline
20 &  5 & 70 & 16 & 42 & 80 & 68 & 59 & 38 \\
\hline
63 & 18 & 77 & 30 & 75 & 46 & 74 &  6 & 10 \\
\hline
21 & 55 & 51 & 29 & 62 & 32 &  7 & 54 & 23 \\
\hline
33 & 48 & 58 & 45 & 39 & 28 & 12 & 76 & 71 \\
\hline
25 &  9 & 69 & 24 & 73 & 37 & 26 & 53 & 47 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

For $7\times7$ contiguous subgrids, I could not find a solution.

A solution for $7 \times 7$ grid cells with $2 \times 2$ subgrids with sum $99$:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
49 & 1 & 48 & 2 & 47 & 3 & 46 \\
\hline
4 & 45 & 5 & 44 & 6 & 43 & 7 \\
\hline
42 & 8 & 41 & 9 & 40 & 10 & 39 \\
\hline
11 & 38 & 12 & 37 & 13 & 36 & 14 \\
\hline
35 & 15 & 34 & 16 & 33 & 17 & 32 \\
\hline
18 & 31 & 19 & 30 & 20 & 29 & 21 \\
\hline
28 & 22 & 27 & 23 & 26 & 24 & 25 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: I think when OP said $3\times 3$ grid, they meant a contiguous subgrid, spanning a $3\times 3$ square. Your program is requiring non-contiguous subgrids to have the same sum as well.

Comment: in other words, sum (a1,a2,a3, b1,b2,b3, c1,c2,c3) should be 369, as well as sum(b1,b2,b3, c1,c2,c3, d1,d2,d3) wjth classic conventions. In your 1st example, the sum 1+79+57+17+72+43+13+56+50 is not valid.